# Excel VBA - Issues with Find(Cell.Value) and formatting

Tags: excel, find, vba

I have several columns of data with various headings that I would like to narrow down and organize according to their headings. Right now I'm accomplishing my task by copying the data under each heading on my source sheet, finding the same heading on a destination sheet, and pasting under the new heading. My code is:

```
For Each Cell In NewData 'where NewData is the range with all of the headings
    Range(Cell.Offset(1, 0), Cell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Copy
    Worksheets("Total").Activate
    Worksheets("Total").Rows(2).Find(Cell.Value).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    On Error Resume Next
'error handling skips data columns in sheet 1 that are not found in sheet 2
Next Cell
```

I have two examples of my problem:

1). Some of my data headings are "5/64", "6/64", and "7/64", which when pasted into Excel returns as a date format. The Cell.Text returns, for example, "May-64" instead of "5/64", while the Cell.Value returns "5/1/1964". This is fine with me, as long as its consistent throughout, but my sub is entering data from the heading "5.5" into the column that should only be "5/64" (or since I'm using Cell.Value, "5/1/1964").

2). Similarly to the first example, I have two data columns "Total Protein" and "Total Protein(NIR)", where data from "Total Protein" is being pasted under the "Total Protein(NIR)" heading.

For both of these examples I'm guessing there's a problem with how I am handling the Cell.Value. Using Cell.Text instead doesn't work either; this skips the "May-64" headings entirely. Any tips?

Comment: Perhaps wrap `Cell.Value` with `Cstr()`. So `CStr(Cell.Value)`.

Comment: For number 2 (and possibly number 1 too), you'll probably need to specify a full match in the `Find` function: eg `Find(What:=Cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)`. This should make sure "Total Protein(NIR)"is matched correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Socii had the right idea - specifying LookAt:=xlWhole fixed the issue. Thanks for the responses